# AppEngine Standard Environment Pub/Sub Context in Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, publish-subscribe

Trying to get Pub/Sub working in AppEngine Standard Environment. Having problems getting the right context. The Pub/Sub client wants a `context.Context` but AppEngine only has `appengine.Context`. Can't find any examples or anything related to this, except for flexible environment (using `context.Background`) which I don't want to use. Am I the only person on the planet wanting to use Pub/Sub with AppEngine Standard Environment?

Comment: The [appengine API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference#NewContext) gives you a `context.Context`. See also [here](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine#NewContext). What version of Go are you using?

Comment: Using Go 1.9. When calling `appengine.NewContext` I'm getting an `appengine.Context`

Comment: I'm importing `appengine` and `cloud.google.com/go/pubsub`

Comment: When you say you are importing `appengine`, are you importing `google.golang.org/appengine` like the [Go 1.9 examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/appengine/helloworld/hello.go)? Also, make sure your [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/download) is up to date

Comment: This is really interesting and quite bizarre. I have always used just `appengine` and everything I've done over the past few years have always accepted an `appengine.Context` and now when I change it to `google.golang.org/appengine` I suddenly get a `context.Context` but now all my other code that uses `appengine.Context` doesn't work because it's expecting a different context. What is the difference between `appengine.Context` and `context.Context`? I must be missing something.

Comment: `context.Context` was introduced in [Go 1.7](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#context) (2016) `appengine.NewContext` was changed to return `context.Context` [in 2017](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/release-notes#august_9_2017). I suggest you change all your other code to use `context.Context`

Comment: Thank you so very much for clarifying everything

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I was using the wrong `appengine`. As of now, I have to import `google.golang.org/appengine` like the [examples for Go 1.9](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/appengine/helloworld/hello.go). This is because I was providing `appengine.context` when I needed `context.Context`.

`context.Context` was introduced in [Go 1.7 (2016)](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#context). `appengine.NewContext` was changed to return `context.Context` [in 2017](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/release-notes#august_9_2017).

Comment: I have tried to add all the info from the comments into the answer. Please, check if this is correct.